# Negative margins not rendering correctly in non-Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a website and using codes below.Chrome seems to work fine, but Firefox doesn't read negative margin and IE completely doesn't load it correctly :

Background of form :

```
<div class="pageB" style="opacity:0.8;position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: #000000; z-index: 200; display: none; font-weight: bold; color: White; font-size: 16pt;direction: rtl;">
<div class="userlogin">
<div id=top>
<div class=s1></div>
<div class=s2></div>
<div class=s3></div>
<div class=s4></div>
</div>
<div id=round>
<div align="right" dir="rtl" style="float: right;"><img src="/Files/close.png" width="24" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="AnimateBoxBack()"></div>
</div>
<div id=bottom>
<div class=s4></div>
<div class=s3></div>
<div class=s2></div>
<div class=s1></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Main Form :

```
<div class="login-box">
Username :
<input type="text" style="width: 99%;" name="username" class="username" onfocus="AnimateBox()" /><br />
Password : <input style="width: 99%;" type="password" name="password" class="password" onfocus="AnimateBox()" /><br />
<input type="radio" name="chkAdm" class="chkAdm" id="admin" checked="checked">Admin&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="chkAdm" class="chkAdm" id="user">User<br /><br />
<button class="rounded" onclick="Login()"><span>Login</span></button>
</div>
```

the javascript code that animates it :

```
function AnimateBox()
{
    $(".PageB").css("display","block");
    $(".login-box").css("position", "fixed");
    $(".login-box").css("z-index", "300");// : "300"
    $(".login-box").animate({
        "top" : "50%",
        "left" : "50%",
        "margin-top" : "-140px",
        "margin-left" : "-175px"
    },1000);
    loginAnimated = true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing (IE6 doesn't support `position:fixed`; IE6,7,8 don't support `opacity`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it should work in all 3 browsers you mention([example](http://www.brunildo.org/test/bfc-neg-marg-float.html)), I've used negative margins every now and then (*but you should try to avoid them*), so there has to something else going wrong with your page.

However, this is not the reason I'm writing this answer. The reason people use negative margins is to position a `div` without knowing the aspect ratios or screen size before the page is fully rendered, i.e., when placing it in a CSS stylesheet. You on the other hand, can know exactly what the screen size is, by:

```
$(window).width(); // Window width;
$(document).width(); // HTML width;
```

So you can use:

```
$(".login-box").animate({
    "top" : (0.5 * $(window).height()) - 140,
    "left" : (0.5 * $(window).width()) - 175
}, 1000);
```

Which allows you to use a `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` without negative margins, without loss of functionality and consistency throughout all 3 browsers you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `position: relative` and `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left`.

Comment: but isn't there anyway to use fixed position?? it is too important for me